# Adding QGraphicsView offsets QTouchPositions

Tags: c++, qt, touch

im currently struggling with my application using a touch interface together with QT.
The application consists of a QStackWidget, which can change its contents (page) by user interactions with another QWidget.

For most pages, this works well. However, when i select our map page, that is represented by a map class inheriting from QGraphicsView, the entire touch mapping is offsetted by a certain value (~150 px in y-Direction), regardless of whether i am still showing the map content or another page.
I found out, that the offset does not occur, when i leave out the following line inside the map class:

```
setViewport(glWidget);
```

The problem is that i need the line for the map to run properly.
Is there any obvious reason, that could lead to this offset or any workaround that could fix my problem?

Thanks in advance

SegfaultCreator

Comment: When OpenGL comes into play this might become source of some subtle effects. With just your rough description this might be hard to sort out. (I immediately got some ideas what might go wrong but these are all guesses out of the blue.) Better, you try to provide a [mcve]. Additionally, it would be nice if your [mcve] could demonstrate your issue with mouse events. (I assume you have an issue with coordinates which are not strongly related to the touch event. Not everybody has a touch screen at hand.)

Comment: FYI: [Qt doc.: Coordinate System](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/coordsys.html)

Comment: "Additionally, it would be nice if your minimal reproducible example could demonstrate your issue with mouse events."
Unfortunately, this is NOT the case. Instead the mouse positions are not offsetted and therefore work well.
I will strive to provide such an example, however it is not that easy and might take some time

Comment: Issues which happen in a touch event but not in a mouse event constrain IMHO the possible sources.